# Correcting binding errors after reusing a View for two different (almost identical) ViewModels

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have one View that displays a video.  A video can be either recorded (on the device) or downloaded (and subsequently had some validation operation on it).  We have a ViewModel to represent each state although they share a common ViewModel base class.

We reuse the same view for both as they are 99% identical.  The downloaded ViewModel has a couple of extra properties related to the validation (whether its been accepted or rejected).  Given that we use the same view this generates binding errors for the Recorded videos.

How can I work around this problem?  I would have thought that if these visual elements were invisible they wouldnt generate binding errors (they are invisible unless its on a saved recording)

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ValidationHistory" Visibility="{Binding IsSavedRecording, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Visible}">
    <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding HasAcceptedValidationSessions, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Visible}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberOfAcceptedValidationSessions, FallbackValue=0}"  />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Is there a big problem with binding errors (are you logging binding errors?) - most of the time you can safely leave a binding error (if it's something of this nature). Alternatively, you could break this and the validation history section down into their own separate view/viewmodels and composite them into the view when needed. This way you would only see the area when you decided it needed to be included - but you'd still need to bind something. Are you using any particular MVVM framework?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the errors?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is to use are DataTemplates.

### A very rough description

You create two Templates for the relevant parts of the view, for example, containing the `StackPanel` or not.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template1" DataType="{x:Type m:ValidationHistoryViewModel}">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ValidationHistory">...*your critical binding*...</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="Template2" DataType="{x:Type m:OtherViewModel}">
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you implement a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) which decides which Template (Template1 or 2) should be used by which ViewModel Type.

Last but not least, in your View, you need to use a `<ContentPresenter>` at the relevant point, and you can configure the `ContentPresenter`s `DataTemplateSelector` to your specific selector.

This (quite old) [Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18777/Routed-Template-Selection-in-WPF) will help you understanding it, what you need to change is the fact that you don't use a list of items but one, that's why you want to use a `ContentPresenter` for this. The official [MSDN resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) should also be helpful.